# Driver to simulate keypresses into another process

Tags: keyboard, console, framebuffer

How can I simulate a key being pressed in a given process on Linux? Xorg isn't running, the inputs are handled by DirectFB

Comment: I can tell you how to simulate key presses to the system, but not directed to a specific process. If the process was focuses then it would get them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish here... more information about your goals would be very helpful.

To communicate between different processes you either need to use [signals](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/all-about-linux-signals?page=show) (or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208004/how-do-signal-work)) or that specific program's API (e.g., [Xorg](http://www.x.org/wiki/Development)'s development wiki).

Comment: more details here: http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/37365-linux-driver-to-simulate-keypresses/

Comment: Your link doesn't help me, because it doesn't tell me *why* you want to do this... there might be a better way. I'm not a systems programmer, but I'm pretty sure you want to use signals... either way, my gut says this should be on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you'd want to use a pipe to input info to other processes. What your program could do is close the stdio input file descriptor and open a new file descriptor that your program uses to write to the process. A good source you may like is beejs guide to posix programming. look it up, it has what you need.