# where can I find signal and alarm function definitions?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I studied about signal and alarm functions but not satisfied hence thought that their definitions can help me.

Comment: Try the man pages ? e.g. http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal ?

Answer (score 1):

THIS MIGHT help----->. Good Explanations ::

1.http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Signal-Handling.html#Signal-Handling

2.http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node24.html

3.http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/catch-signals-sample-c-code/

Answer (score 1):

The signal(3) C library function is usually a thin wrapper around a system call to the underlying kernel. alarm(3) does a bit more work, but again falls back on the kernel's idea of time handling and signal delivery.

If you *really* want to know how they work, you'd have to dig into the source of a Unix(y) kernel. Be warned, the code you'll find is probably very complex, kernel programmers have to handle some very exotic corner cases, and be wary of weird uses thay might lead to security problems. All that while keeping it as fast as possible (it's code that'll be used hundreds or thousands of times a second on millions of machines).

Next best would be to check out a book on Unix internals.

Answer (score 0):

`Man pages` are the best places to know about the working and usage of any system-defined function. From your question, you actually mean the implementations of the functions(I guess).
But ask yourself, why do you need to look into the code? All that happens is it induces more questions, since most of the variables and functions used will be defined somewhere else and you need to look into them again.

If you are so dissatisfied, then try some tough problems involving these functions.

Comment: I am not satisfied with what I have studied, I need to know the concept behind their implementation at least.

Comment: You need to be clear about that in your question. I hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208004/how-do-signals-work) might help... :)