# How signals are handled in kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, signals

How are the signals handled in the kernel. What happens internally if I send a kill signal to a kernel thread/process.
Does a crash in kernel process means kernel panic always, if not will it generate coredump.

Comment: This would be more appropriate for unix.stackexchange.com. SO is for programming questions, not questions about the design and implementation of Unix/Linux.

Comment: Looks like a close duplicate of [How do signals work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208004/how-do-signals-work). Does the info there answer your question?

Comment: No, want to know signal delivery to kernel process that never go to user space.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355280/how-signals-are-handled-in-kernel